# Nodejs node-mysql query result data type

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I have trouble figuring out how to get the data from mysql Queries in the callback function. For example I have the query as follows:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) from card AS count', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } 
    else {
        console.log(Type.of(result));
        console.log("card count is as: " + result.count);
        console.log("Card count is: " + result["COUNT(*)"]);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

This prints out:

```
[Function: Array]
card count is as: undefined
Card count is: undefined
[ { 'COUNT(*)': 3 } ]
```

What is a "[Function: Array]" datatype and how do you pick variables from it? An array of functions? Why is "result.count" undefined even though I in the query I use the AS thing.

Also how is the following query different from the one below it?

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) from card AS count', function (err, rows, fields) {
});

mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) from card AS count', function (err, result) {
});
```

When do I use the other and when the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback with `function (err, rows, fields)` is much more appropriate for selecting data you are working with, and rows will then be populated by an array of arrays.  So, in your case `rows[0]['COUNT(*)']` would be your count.

For selects with multiple rows, you can loop through the results.

As a side note, I think you meant `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from card` which would then be accessible much more simply as `rows[0].count`

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from card
```

The column alias should be defined after selecting the column, not after the `from`.